# Symfony debug still enabled after cache:warmup --no-debug

Tags: symfony, caching

I have Symfony 3.2.7 installed on a production server.
I issue the following commands:

```
bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup --no-debug --env=preview
bin/console cache:warmup --no-debug --env=preview
bin/console --version
```

I get the following output, showing that debug is enabled.

> Symfony 3.2.7 (kernel: app, env: preview, debug: true)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind.
Bad programmer on device.
The monolog.handlers.main.level value was set to debug.
Duh. 
Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used bin/console in a production server, but I don't think that information is reliable for your use case.

If you open the bin/console script in an editor you will see:

```
$debug = getenv('SYMFONY_DEBUG') !== '0' && !$input->hasParameterOption(['--no-debug', '']) && $env !== 'prod';
```

As you can see the $debug parameter is determined by a combination of environment variables and parameters.

Every time you call this script this value is recalculated.

Comment: There is something to be gained here. If someone else makes the same mistake, this post should show up in a search. I certainly searched before posting.